# How to authenticate app to respond to webhook events

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, webhooks, exact-online

I seem to be overlooking something quite fundamental regarding authentication when trying to automate an API request in response to receiving a webhook notification, and any help would be appreciated.

I am comfortable creating a custom app to work with the Exact Online API in my browser through oauth2 authorisation code authentication. I have also set up webhooks so that Exact Online sends notifications to a URL which then receives, validates and saves the data, and this takes place without a browser connection or oauth2 authentication. However, I would like to run API queries on receipt of webhook notifications so that they run automatically and I do not know how to obtain the oauth2 authorisation code.

Webhook data is easily received (without validating) as follows:

```
http_response_code(200); // Tell Exact I have received the data
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

I can easily capture the input data on a web page which does not have an open oauth2-authenticated channel to Exact Online, and the webhook notification takes place without opening a browser instance. Also, it is easy to open an oauth2-authenticated API link by sending

```
$authCodeRequest = "https://start.exactonline.co.uk/api/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%-my-client-id-%7D&redirect_uri=my-site-redirect";
header('Location: ' . $authCodeRequest);
die('Request failed');
```

and using a $_GET['code'] to get the authorisation code to use in the request for access token and refresh token.
But how can I run an API query on receipt of a webhook? - I cannot see how to allow for access between the page which is not open on the browser and Exact Online.

I have tried including an authorisation request on the page receiving the webhook:

```
$authCodeRequest = "https://start.exactonline.co.uk/api/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%-my-client-id-%7D&redirect_uri=my-site-redirect";
header('Location: ' . $authCodeRequest);
die(fwrite('Request failed'));
```

This makes sense, because the page could not magically open in a random browser to request user login.

I also tried making the API page the url for receipt of webhook notifications, and then authenticating the page before running a webhook event. This also did not work, as the webhook notification would be sent to a different instance of the page.

Exact Online does not allow for user credentials authentication - only for implicit and authorisation code authentication - and both of these require login. How do I authenticate to allow the processing of webhooks when I receive a notification? Or, is there some online resource I can look at to understand what it is that I am missing?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/exactonline/exactonline-api-php-client

Comment: Thanks, Carmel - I think Lennert's method will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the OAuth flow once to fetch the tokens. Save the refresh token.
When you get a webhook notification, get new tokens with the previously saved refresh token. Don't forget to save the new refresh token as the old tokens are no longer valid.
Get the data.

Comment: Thanks, Lennert - this makes sense: I will give it a try.